# Is this usage of "vary" correct?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> While the use of allegory has traditionally varied from texts which “abstract the narrative . . . into the theological or doctrinal structure that informs it” to more ironic allegories which “challenge the authority of the pretext by drawing it into history and so marking its lapse into semantic mutability” (Clarke 23), the form and content of allegory itself has transformed in response to technological developments. ([source](http://cafeirreal.alicewhittenburg.com/review1a.htm))

Can this verb be used like this?
Like "I changed this from A to B?"

Answer (score 5):

This *vary* is intransitive, meaning: ***differ in nature*** (the use of allegory).

From [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/vary),

> **vary**
>   <sup>VERB</sup>
>   1 [intransitive] to be different in different situations
>   *The details may vary, but all of these savings plans have the same basic goal.*
>
> > **vary according to/depending on:** *Car taxes will now vary according to the amount of carbon dioxide a particular car emits.*
> >     **vary with:** *Fees vary with the size of the job.*
> >     **vary considerably/greatly/widely/enormously:** *People's reactions to the drug can vary widely.*
> >     **vary from... to...:** *The planning laws vary from town to town.*

Comment: But this sentence doesn't make any sense.

Comment: It has ***varied from*** (texts which “abstract the narrative ...) ***to*** (more ironic allegories ...); quite similar to the last example in Macmillan.